# Отличия между GTK 2 и GTK 3, а так же отличия версий Glade

Tags: c, windows, gtk3, glade, gtk2

Подскажите, чем различаются версии **Glade: 3.8.5 и 3.22.1** ?
И в чем разница между **GTK 2 и GTK 3**?

Я хочу разрабатывать **GUI** на **GTK+** под **Windows 10**. Для этого я установил стек всех требуемых инструментов и зависимостей **GTK 3** через **MSYS2**, используя официальное руководство.

Но проблема в том, что **Glade 3.22.1**, установленный через **MSYS2**, визуально очень кривой и в процессе работы постоянно падает. То есть, работать в нем невозможно. Строить интерфейс через ручное описание в коде программы или в xml я не могу, потому что интерфейс очень сложный.

Я попытался установить **Glade 3.14.2** из **exe**, но он тоже постоянно падает.

Попробовал скачать **Glade 3.8.5** с сайта **gnome**. Он выглядит гораздо удобнее, пока не падал, но меня смущает вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделанный таким образом интерфейс удалось загрузить программно через использование **GtkBuilder**, но меня все же очень беспокоит вопрос версионности.

Comment: Насколько знаю, glade только начиная с 3.8 начал поддерживать gtk3

Comment: Откуда эта информация?

Comment: Разница описана туть: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/migrating-2to3.html А касательно разработки, можно под Окна и из-под Линукс писать